# Generating a list with string and number

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to generate a list that looks like this:

list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9'], ['c1', 'c2', .........],......
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']

The code I put in is as follows:

```
rows = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
newrow=[]
for i in rows:
    print('')
    for j in range(9):
    newrow.append(i + str(j+1))

print(list(newrow))
```

Clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: You're only missing indentation on the line for `newrow.append(i + str(j+1))`.

Comment: Sorry that indentation was a mistake in the code I typed here. I actually have that. That I need is a list of lists. Please note the square brackets between a9 and b1 list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9'], ['c1', 'c2', .........],...... ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']

Comment: Your code works well with that indentation on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

You need an indent for the content underneath the for loop. Otherwise, it skips it entirely because it doesn't think the loop has any body.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print("Do something");
```

NOT

```
for i in range(1,10):
print("Do something");
```

The code above will print once. The first example would print 10 times.

Comment: Sorry that indentation was a mistake in the code I typed here. I actually have that. What I am looking for is a list of lists. Please note the square brackets between a9 and b1. Thank You.                                                                   list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9'], ['c1', 'c2', .........],...... ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as a list comprehension

```
rows = ['a','b','c']
newrow = [[i+str(j) for j in range(1,10)] for i in rows]
```

The list comprehension is usually faster than the for loop because it doesn't have to look up the list every time it wants to append a value.

Comment: Thank you for the list comprehension code. I am not up to speed on these yet. However what I am looking for is a list of lists. Please note the square brackets between a9 and b1. Would appreciate if you can show me the code for this using the list comprehension method.  Thank You. 
       list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9'], ['c1', 'c2', .........],...... ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']

Comment: Updated my code. Please accept the answer if it is exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks. That was neat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain each letter as a separate list (maintain the brackets on your first example), you need to append for each letter, then append for each number within the inner loop:

```
rows = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
newrow = []
for i in range(len(rows)):
    newrow.append([])
    for j in range(9):
        newrow[i-1].append(rows[i] + str(j+1))

print(list(newrow))
```

But I really do suggest you look into list comprehension, @lordingtar 's answer is a nested list comprehension, they may look difficult at first, but once you get used to them they're really very easy.